# Depreciating an investment property & tax strategy

Tags: united-states, taxes

This is regarding US Federal taxes (and California state taxes). Last year in February we purchased a second home property (via mortgage) and have made numerous renovations and repairs to it up until present day (i.e. in both tax year '21 and '22). I have decided I will be renting it out in the next couple of months, so as far as I know, the property is not considered 'in service' as of yet.

For tax year 2021 - as I understand it I will not be able to start depreciating the property yet (I will in year 2022 assuming I advertise it for rent). So, other than possibly deducting mortgage interest (if it ends up being worth it tbd) or property taxes - is there anything special I should be doing on my taxes for '21?

One thing I don't understand, are the capital improvements I did in 2021 (when it was not in service) treated any differently than the ones I do when it *is* in service? I.e. do I still get to depreciate those on my next tax return that the property goes into service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, other than possibly deducting mortgage interest (if it ends up being worth it tbd) or property taxes - is there anything special I should be doing on my taxes for '21?

You can deduct the mortgage (up to limitations), but you'll likely not be able to deduct taxes. I assume you have salary income, and you mentioned it's a second property, so you have a first (also in California?), which means that you're likely to significantly exceed the SALT 10K limitation. You can still deduct it on your CA taxes though.

> are the capital improvements I did in 2021 (when it was not in service) treated any differently than the ones I do when it is in service?

No. You can still depreciate them when you put it in service. See the [IRS Pub 946](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p946#en_US_2020_publink1000107332):

> **Conversion to business use.**
>
> If you place property in service in a personal activity, you cannot claim depreciation. However, if you change the property's use to use in a business or income-producing activity, then you can begin to depreciate it at the time of the change. You place the property in service in the business or income-producing activity on the date of the change.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - at my current residence I rent, I called this property a 'second home' since that's the mortgage we got for it (and as far as I understand there is nothing wrong with converting it to an investment property after a year or so). I do have salary income yes.

Comment: @user67081 You'll probably exceed the SALT limitation with just the salary, no need to be super rich to pay 10K in CA income taxes...

Comment: One follow-up, when filling Sched A and adding property taxes - can these be taxes that were assessed in 2021 and paid in 2022 or must they be both assessed and paid in 2021 to add them on the return for 2021?

Comment: @user67081 if you're cash based taxpayer (which you almost certainly are) that what matters is when you paid them.